# Same HTML code works for some images and not others

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a simple website and cannot seem to figure out a small problem. Whenever I insert an image (all images are in an Images subfolder) I use the exact same image code. However, for some reason some of the images show up as broken links when I put the website on a server and access it that way. I access the exact same place from the server locally and the images look just fine. When accessed from the server through the internet only the first image in the table shows up. I know the files are not corrupted and every other reference throughout the website works just fine. Any thoughts?

Edit: The permissions are the same for every image in the folder. Read/Execute on all files.

```
<div id="headshots">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:center">THE TEAM</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><a href = "Images/Example0.jpg"><img src="Images/Example0.jpg" alt="****" /></a></td>
            <td><a href = "Images/Example1.jpg"><img src="Images/Example1.jpg" alt="****" /></a></td>
            <td><a href = "Images/Example2.jpg"><img src="Images/Example2.jpg" alt="****" /></a></td>
            <td><a href = "Images/Example3.jpg"><img src="Images/Example3.jpg" alt="****" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:white" bgcolor="#C59353">Example0</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:white" bgcolor="#C59353">Example1</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:white" bgcolor="#C59353">Example2</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:white" bgcolor="#C59353">Example3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the main difference here is that locally you're using Windows while your server is using Linux. The main thing to look out for in Linux vs. Windows is case-sensitivity. Say, if one of your images is named `example1.jpg` or `Example1.JPG`, it will not work with your code.

I am almost certain that this is the solution to your problem, although it's actually more of a guess, so if you have additional information please post it here.

Comment: I never thought of checking the capitalization of the file extension! I had no idea this affected anything on any platform. That fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Cheers, glad to be of help. Please don't forget to accept the answer :)